# How do I search for an item in an array in Hive?

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

Using Hive I've created a table with the following fields:

- ID BIGINT,
- MSISDN STRING,
- DAY TINYINT,
- MONTH TINYINT,
- YEAR INT,
- GENDER TINYINT,
- RELATIONSHIPSTATUS TINYINT,
- EDUCATION STRING,
- LIKES_AND_PREFERENCES STRING

This was filled with data via the following SQL command:

```
Insert overwrite table temp_output Select a.ID, a.MSISDN, a.DAY, a.MONTH, a.YEAR, a.GENDER, a.RELATIONSHIPSTATUS, b.NAME,  COLLECT_SET(c.NAME) FROM temp_basic_info a JOIN temp_education b ON (a.ID = b.ID) JOIN likes_and_music c ON (c.ID = b.ID) GROUP BY a.ID, a.MSISDN, a.DAY, a.MONTH, a.YEAR, a.Gender, a.RELATIONSHIPSTATUS, b.NAME;
```

Likes and Preferences is an array, but I was not foresighted enough to specify it as such (it's a string, instead). How would I go about selecting records that have a specific item in the array?

Is it as simple as:

```
select * from table_result where LIKES_AND_PREFERENCES = "item"
```

Or will that have some unforeseen issues?

I tried that query above, and it does seam to output the files with only the "items" in the array, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should try something like this:

```
select * from (
select col1,col2..coln, new_column from table_name lateral view explode(array_column_name) exploded_table as new_column 
) t where t.new_column = '<value of items to be searched>'
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: It returns the following: `FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter`. The LIKES_AND_PREFERENCES in the explode().

Comment: Yes **explode()** function takes array as argument.
But your **LIKES_AND_PREFERENCES** is a STRING, may be you need to check that first. Check here for creation of array a column: 
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270084/whats-the-best-way-to-support-array-column-types-with-external-tables-in-hive**

Comment: Oh, crap. That's right. In that regard, would my simple select statement from above work?

Comment: It only returns the results with that exact value, but I guess I can use the 'like' statement for it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hive does not have LIKE equivalent of RDBMS, you need to use RLIKE or REGEXP. Also you can use CASE.
Check this out: 
1.)**https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#Relational_Operators**
2.)**https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#Conditional_Functions**

Answer (score 4):

Using the array_contains udf in the following manner --

```
 select * 
 from mytable 
 where array_contains(likes_and_preferences,'item') = TRUE
```

array_contains will return a Boolean that you can predicate on.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the function you used will return only records where array has only one element with value : "item"

You need to use : array_contains function.

Comment: How do I use `array_contains` in a query?

Comment: array_contains(array_to_search, value) - return a boolean. Documentation here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF