# Query within an Array in hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906226/how-do-i-search-for-an-item-in-an-array-in-hive) but it does not work on my data.

I have this data:

```
 1, John, a@com;b@com2,32
 2, Jack, ab@com;c@com2,33
```

and loaded them to hive by:

```
create table t7(id int,name string, email Array<string>, age int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION items terminated by ';'
STORED AS textfile;
Load data inpath '/user/maria_dev/7.txt' into table t7;
```

and the select output

[image]

but I cannot search specific value whithin the array
[image]

[image]

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that yours does not work is that you have whitespace before the first element so you have to use trim

```
select * from t7 where trim(email[0]) like "%a@%";
```

```
CREATE TABLE `t7`(
  `id` int,
  `name` string,
  `email` array<string>,
  `age` int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\;'

hive> select * from t7 where trim(email[0])="a@com";
OK
1        John   [" a@com","b@com2"]     32

hive> select * from t7 LATERAL VIEW explode(email) exploded_table as id_email where id_email like "%com2%";
OK
1        John   [" a@com","b@com2"]     32      b@com2
2        Jack   [" ab@com","c@com2"]    33      c@com2
```

Comment: thanks, why have you used '\;' instead of ';'? mine works fine, any specific reason?

Comment: ';' is not working correctly for me, use '\\;' instead?